# Может ли быть более одной ФСР?

Tags: математика, линейная-алгебра

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вопрос как всегда бесконечно глупый, изучаю линейную алгебру, пользуюсь задачником Гусевой. По условию одного из заданий нам нужно найти ортонормированный базис ортогонального дополнения к линейной оболочке системы векторов, сами вектора

> a1 = (1,2,-1,-3)
>
> a2 = (2,1,1,-9)
>
> a3 = (1,4,-3,-1)

После проверки линейной независимости и получения ранга матрицы методом Гаусса имеем матрицу следующего вида:

```
1 2 -1 -3

0 -3 3 -3 

0 0 0 0
```

Нулевой вектор a3 вычеркиваем, таким образом L опеределно векторами a1,a2.
Далее необходимо дополнить до R4, насколько мне известно сделать это можно нахождением ФСР чтобы при этом выполнялось

> (a1,bi)=0
>
> (a2,bi)=0

и b1,b2 являлись решением системы из двух уравнений (a1,x)=0,(a2,x)=0
Путем нехитрых преобразований получил такую вот систему

> x1-3x2+3x3-3x4=0
>
> 2x1+x2+x3-9x4=0

Слева оставил только базисный минор и получил соответственно
-3x2=-3x3+3x4
2x1+x2=-3x3+9x4
Через зависимые x1,x2 выразил свободные x3,x4  и получил

> x2=x3-x4
> x1=-x3+5x4

ФСР

> b1 -1 1 1 0
>
> b2 5 -1 0 1

Скалярное произведение a1,b1 a2,b2 равно нулю, все кажется правильным. Но в ответах к задачнику указаны совершенно другие вектора:
если это возможно, пожалуйста укажите что я сделал не так, может быть чего-то не сделал или допустил ошибку на каком-то конкретном этапе. Заранее благодарю за любую помощь[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но ведь нулевой вектор может получиться, если вектора линейно зависимы, а они не похожи на линейно зависимые.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Более одной ФРС, действительно может быть. Можно, например, повернуть систему векторов на произвольный угол:

```
с1 = b1*cos(a) + b2*sin(-a)
с2 = b1*sin(a) + b2*cos(a)
```

Легко показать, что если исходная система (b1,b2) ортонормированная, то и (с1,с2) - ортонормированная, причем оба вектора принадлежат линейной оболочке (b1,b2).

Однако, ошибка у вас есть: по условию задачи, требуется найти ортонормированный базис. Для ваших векторов: `b1.b2 = -6`.
Ортогонализуем:

```
с1 = b1
с2 = b2 - b1 (b1.b2)/(b1.b1)
```

Получим ответ, совпадающий с ответом задачника.

Совпадение ответов, не совсем случайно. Это произошло потому, что задачник предлагает определенный алгоритм действий, который приводит к конкретному ответу.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, разобрался. Подскажите,а как быть если вектор всего один, допустим как для примера 2) того же номера со скриншота? Насколько я понимаю (исходя из ответа в конце учебника) нужно некоторым образом дополнить и решать стандартным методом,как я могу это сделать или где прочесть инструкцию для не очень умных людей?

Comment: @desomorph1ne Вы же уже решаете стандартным методом. Проверка линейной независимости тривиальная: если вектор ненулевой - то он независим от остальных (потому что остальных нет)...

Comment: Я ямею в виду что в ответах для задания с одним вектором мы получили ОНБ из трех векторов, как это произошло?

Comment: @desomorph1ne Просто система получится из одного уравнения `(a1,bi)=0`. Базовый минор - матрица  1x1 (просто число)  и останется три независимые переменные...